# Material Design Form in HTML not working as expected?

Tags: html, forms, css, material-design

So I am creating a simple login page and I am trying to style it using Googles Material Design, I came across MUI which a CSS3 framework that does just what I want except one simple thing, when I type in the username the floating label does float up and looks cool, but as soon as I move away from that input field the floating label sinks back down which looks incredibly ugly and obviously is not what I want.

I have created a jsfiddle to replicate the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jackherer/fm71qxqq/).

```
<form class="" action="php/process_login.php" method="post">
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="">
        <label>Username</label>
    </div>

    <div class="mui-textfield mui-textfield--float-label">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="">
        <label>Password</label>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="mui-btn mui-btn--raised" value="Login">
    </div>
</form>
```

I have followed a simple guide that demonstrates how this should work [here (Floating Labels)](https://www.muicss.com/docs/v1/css-js/forms?) and it works well.

Could anyone suggest how I can fix this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to load also MUI javascript with

```
<script src="//cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.9.3/js/mui.min.js"></script>
```

Working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/fm71qxqq/2/).

Comment: Thanks Paolo, I feel kinda stupid now. I have been awake for over two days coding a basic CMS from scratch without any tutorials and decided to cool off on the deep coding and just do a bit of front end designing when I hit this issue **sleep is definitely needed** cheers

Answer (score 0):

You haven't embed the Javascript file, paste this in of your top of you page in the head section:

```
<script src="//cdn.muicss.com/mui-0.9.3/js/mui.min.js"></script>
```